# how to get credit score via online api in india and i dont get any from internet search?

Tags: api

i want to check the credit score like IND_CIBIL score via a API integration 
      for checking individual credit score

Comment: You might possibly get an answer on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: didn't get there also :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but at least you discovered a useful site. Also useful is [the world's biggest collection of APIs](https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory). Good luck